# Why does my column exist in my pyspark dataframe after dropping it?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am using pyspark version 2.4.5 and Databricks runtime 6.5 and I have run into unexpected behavior. My code is as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_A = spark.table(...)
df_B = df_A.drop(
    F.col("colA")
)
df_C = df_B.filter(
    F.col("colA") > 0
)
```

When I assign df_C by filtering on df_B I expect an error to be thrown as "colA" has been dropped. But this code works fine when I run it. Is this expected or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark constructs an explain plan that makes sense and applies the `drop` after the `filter`. You can see that from the explain plan e.g.

```
spark.createDataFrame([('foo','bar')]).drop(col('_2')).filter(col('_2') == 'bar').explain()
```

Gives:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [_1#0]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(_2#1) && (_2#1 = bar))
   +- Scan ExistingRDD[_1#0,_2#1]
```

In the above explain plan, the projection of the dropped column happens after the filter.